# How to change value of a variable in php by clicking a link or radio button or checkbox

Tags: php

I am creating a system in php to get user's feedback on solutions. I am using MySQL to get the solution and store the feedback. The feedback are integers. There are two columns for feedback- Yes and No. I want to increase the value of them when a user clicks on a text link/radio button or checkbox.
Like-
.................Solution..............
Did this help you? Yes / No

When user clicks on Yes, it should increase value of yes column by one and if it clicks on No, it should increase value of no column by one.
The main difficulty is this that the page contains numbers of solution and feedback options..
Can you help me??

Answer (score 1):

Clicking a form control on a page is a client-side action.  Updating a variable in PHP is a server-side action.  Luckily, AJAX gives us a way of accessing server resources from the client.

The following code performs an AJAX request using the jQuery JavaScript library.  You do not need jQuery to perform AJAX requests, but then you must code your AJAX request natively.  Doing that is not hard, but it's not exactly trivial, either.

JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/path/to/file.php',
    data: 'url=encoded&query=string', // Can also be an object
    success: function( output ) {
        // This function gets called once the AJAX Request returns.  It is sent 
        // a string parameter containing all output of the Server-side script
    }
});
```

In the `file.php`, you just perform whatever actions you want to.  The AJAX request can be sent either via GET or POST, and any variables passed will be available in the `$_GET` and `$_POST` superglobals, respectively.

The `output` parameter is passed in is a string, and is all of the output (i.e. `echo`/`print`) that is generated from the server-side script.  That string can be a [JSON representation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) of an object as well, in which case you will have to [parse the string](http://www.json.org/js.html) to be able to use it as an object in JavaScript.  This is beneficial if your server-side script returns large amounts of data instead of just plain HTML/XHTML.

For more information, look at jQuery's [documentation for AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), or Google for [native ajax requests](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery%20ajax&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=m7x&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&sclient=psy-ab&q=native%20ajax%20requests&oq=native%20ajax%20requests&aq=f&aqi=g1g-bK1&aql=&gs_l=serp.3..0j0i8i30.9117.11446.0.11497.20.17.0.0.0.0.265.2082.7j5j4.16.0...0.0.IWRcBvLgphw&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=c906f5821a52c92b&biw=1680&bih=946)

An alternative is just to have your controls as regular form elements which submit the form when they are pressed (e.g., each one of them is a named submit button / image input).  Your form handler will determine which one is pressed depending on what value is present in the `$_POST`.  This method will then send the user input to a form handler which gets executed on the server, which then redirects the user back to the page once it has finished processing.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server side only, so when the user clicks on Yes, it needs to send a request to load a new page, an Ajax request, etc. that will then update the server. Anything done on the page after page load can not be done with PHP.

I would attach $_POST/$_GET requests to each link/radio button that is then sent to MySQL on a page refresh or something to that effect in order to update your table.